# Redshift Copy and row_number function

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there a way to make a Redshift Copy while at the same time generating the row_number() within the destination table?

I am basically looking for the equivalent of the below except that the group of rows does not come from a select but from a copy command for a file on S3

```
insert into aTable
      (id,x,y,z)
  select
      #{startIncrement}+row_number() over(order by x) as id,
      x,y,z,
  from anotherTable;
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question is that, you need to insert an additional column id into table and that id was not there in the csv file. If my understanding is right, please follow the below approach,

> Copy the data from the csv file to a temp table say "aTableTemp" which has the schema without column "id". Then insert data from "aTableTemp" into "aTable" as follows

```
Insert into aTable
Select #{startIncrement}+row_number() over(order by x) as id, * from aTableTemp
```

I hope this should solve your problem

Comment: That is what i did, and it's not efficient. I am looking for for something that does it during the first insertion in the COPY command.

Comment: You cannot insert an additional column while through copy command

Answer (score 0):

Maybe copy into a table with a identity column just don’t copy into that field?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."